# What's the point of destroying ghoul nests?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have never seen the creatures to respawn again, once they were killed in standard combat.

Comment: An OCD-like compulsion to clear every single icon on the map isn't enough?

Comment: I don't suffer such condition :-) I mean, those bombs could be put to some real use right?!

Comment: @Martin Not really a concern since you can meditate for an hour or more and the bombs replenish if you have a strong alcohol. Also, strong alcohol is plentiful in the game

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to repopulation in a very few areas (as mentioned by Aegis), you also get experience points and looting them yields materials.  The bombs regenerate when you meditate, so for me it's an easy choice.

Comment: Tested tonight, small amount of experience (I've got 30 points) and you get to loot the destroyed nest.

Comment: There's definitely good stuff in the nests. Make sure to check each one after you destroy it.

Answer (score 3):

Some areas where the ghoul nests are will become repopulated with people again once the nests are cleared out. You'll know this because a cutscene will trigger with people returning to that area.

Comment: Does this really happen after destroying the nests? Because I already cleared two such areas in Prologue, but it only involved killing the beasts. Not destroying their nests (as far as I can recall).

Comment: @Martin My observation matches yours.

Comment: There was a little village off the coast of a part of Velen I found that was overrun with Ghouls and had a Ghoul nest too. After I cleared the village of them and destroyed the nest the cutscene triggered and people returned to the village.

Comment: I believe this only comes into play where the nest is by an abandoned location (not common at all).

Answer (score 2):

If you're in it for achievements, there's one linked to [destroying all the monster nests in a region](http://www.trueachievements.com/a200109/pest-control-achievement.htm#).